# making a voice assistant in python and gave it a while loop so I can give it another command but when it doesnt recognize my words it ends

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi so I'm making a voice assistant in python and I already made a while loop so that after I ask a question or say an order I can ask again and it works but the problem is that if it doesn't recognize what i said it exits and gives me an error

i've tried watching some youtube tutorials but they are all using different variables and code than me so I can't find the solution there neither can I find the fix on stack overflow...

Here's the code I used

````
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import wikipedia
import datetime
import webbrowser as wb
import pywhatkit
import os
from requests import get


engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) #changing index changes voices but ony 0 and 1 are working here
engine.runAndWait()


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
    return query


def wish():
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir!")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good after noon Sir!")
    elif hour >= 18 and hour < 24:
        speak("Good evening Sir!")
    else:
        speak("Good night sir")
    speak("I am jarvis your personal assistant")


def time():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    speak(Time)


def date():
    year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
    date = int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
    speak(date)
    speak(month)
    speak(year)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    while True:

        query = takeCommand()

        if 'according to wikipedia' in query.lower():
            speak('Searching wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
            speak(results)

        if 'open youtube' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://youtube.com')

        if 'open google' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://google.com')

        if 'open reddit' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://reddit.com')

        if 'open amazon' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://amazon.ae')

        if 'open wikipedia' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://wikipedia.com')

        if 'open discord' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://discord.com/channels/@me')

        if 'open gmail' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://gmail.com')

        if 'open twitter' in query.lower():
            wb.open('https://twitter.com')

        if 'what time is it' in query.lower():
            speak(time())

        if 'what is the day' in query.lower():
            speak(date())

        if 'search' in query.lower():
            search = query.replace('search', '')
            speak('searching ' + search)
            pywhatkit.search(search)

        if 'play' in query.lower():
            song = query.replace('play', '')
            speak('playing ' + song)
            pywhatkit.playonyt(song)

        if "launch notepad" in query.lower():
            npath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe"
            os.startfile(npath)

        if "launch discord" in query.lower():
            npath = "C:\\Users\\Yousif\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\Update.exe"
            os.startfile(npath)

        if "launch steam" in query.lower():
            npath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steam.exe"
            os.startfile(npath)

        if "launch epic games" in query.lower():
            npath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Epic Games\\Launcher\\Portal\\Binaries\\Win32\\EpicGames.exe"
            os.startfile(npath)

        if "what is my ip" in query.lower():
            ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
            speak(f"your IP Address is {ip}")
            print(ip)

        if 'hey jarvis' in query.lower():
            speak("I am here sir")
            print("I am here sir")

        if 'thank you' in query.lower():
            speak("your welcome sir")

        if 'sleep' in query.lower():
            speak("good bye sir")
            exit()```

---

And here's the error I got

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Jarvis Mk2/main.py", line 72, in <module>
    query = takeCommand()
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Jarvis Mk2/main.py", line 37, in takeCommand
    return query
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem lies in your `try.. expept` clause. If youre command is not recognized, the expect clause is triggerd, however after it prints "Sorry, I didn't catch that", you ask it to return `query` nonetheless. `query` is only assinged a value if the `try`-branch is executed successfully though. Therefore you get the UnboundLocalError. To avoid this, try:

```
try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    print(f"user said: {query}\n")

except Exception as e:
    print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
    return ""
return query
```

This will exit without enforcing a value of query. This also will cause all of the if-statements in your while-loop to evaluate to false (trying to process a query that it didn't understand is not sensible, so skipping all ifs is desired behavior). However you might want to think about returning `None` instead and handle this case differently in your while-loop (note: comparisons with `None` or done like `query is\is not None` rather than with the `==` operator).

Also, welcome to stackoverflow, enjoy your stay :) hope this helps,

Rawk

Answer (score 1):

The `return` keyword is outside `try...except`. But `query` is defined only inside the `try...block`. If some exception occurs, it is not defined as the code moves to `except Exception:` block. Then, it executes `return` query, but `query` is not assigned anything.

Move the `return...` inside the `try...block`

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")
        return query
    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
```

Also, use a while loop, which will keep looping until it encounters the return keyword

Comment: This will return None by default, whenever the except clause triggers. This is a sensible thing to do, however this will now throw an error whenever the query is compared to a string inside of the loop. So there needs to be an extra if-clause handling the case that None is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this function:

```py
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
    return query
```

The `query` variable is only defined **if** `r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')` succeeds. If that fails, then `query` is not defined. But you're still trying to return it at the end of the function.

Two solutions:

- Set `query = None` at the beginning of your function
- Or `return None` inside the `except` block

Comment: Luckily I found a fix but thank you very much I appreciate it.